# Typescript syntax: calling a function with < >

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have just seen a piece of code for React that has a syntax I have never seen before. I haven't been able to find what it actualy is. Can someone, please, explain what calling a function with <> instead of () does?

```
const ConfirmationServiceContext = React.createContext<
  // we will pass the openning dialog function directly to consumers
  (options: ConfirmationOptions) => Promise<void>
>(Promise.reject);
```

The piece of code is from [here](https://dev.to/dmtrkovalenko/the-neatest-way-to-handle-alert-dialogs-in-react-1aoe)

Comment: That's not JavaScript. It is TypeScript.

Comment: it is using typescript, thus the different syntax

Comment: I looked more carefully at the article and I noticed too it's typescript. Sorry.

Comment: @vladimir.gorea it’s ok, no worries. Please consider accepting my answer so others might find it useful too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually Typescript type firm for an async lamda.

```
React.createContext<(options: ConfirmationOptions) => Promise<void>>(Promise.reject);
```

`React.createContext` is a Generic type, the `<` and `>` is how we pass the concrete type we're going to use in this instance. Here we're passing an inline function that gets a `ConfirmationOptions` object and returns a `Promise` whose value is `void`